# Verify what client authentication certificates are sent to server?

Tags: ssl, browser, certificate, client-certificates

Is there a way in browser or through some tool to see what SSL certificate (client authentication) was sent to server in request?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like Burp Suite (Free Edition).  It's a darn good proxy for... lots of things.

Answer (score 1):

If your server negotiates the client certificate during the initial handshake (without renegotiation), you should be able to see it using Wireshark: you should see a `Certificate` message coming from the client (not the one coming from the server), after a `Certificate Request` message sent by the server.

If renegotiation is used, this is more complicated.

SSL MITM tools (like Fiddler) won't be of any help, since they perform their own handshakes. Such tools can be configured to fool the client into believing they are the real server, by having the client trust their fake server certificate (a trust setting the user can generally set on the client). However, this doesn't work on when using a client certificate, unless the tool performing the handshake (the SSL MITM tool in this case) was handling the client certificate itself. Otherwise the verification message at the end (which the server uses to verify that the client has the private key for the client certificate) would fail. Some of these tools can indeed be configured with a client certificate, but you need to set them up with the corresponding private key: in this case you would know which client certificate was used.

Another way to check would be to check what the browser itself does. How to do it may depend on the browser. Environment variables like [`SSLDEBUG`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_reference/NSS_environment_variables) might be of interest when using Firefox.